# How can I break through React maps to display object that has two values one with an array other with string or number(result)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a live score website that will be returning all football live events. I am using jquery to send request then getting an object response that has fixures - this contains an array of all live events and finally result - this counts the number of events (21); I have trouble mapping this data so that I can display it on my app attached is the image of response [image]

```
import React from 'react';
import jQuery from 'jquery';
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      liveEvents: '',
      loading: true
    };
  }
  settingState = data => {
    this.setState({
      liveEvents: data.api
    });
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    var h = this;
    var settings = {
      async: true,
      crossDomain: true,
      url: 'https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/fixtures/live',
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'x-rapidapi-host': 'api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com',
        'x-rapidapi-key': 'RAPIDAPI-KEY' //Private
      }
    };

    jQuery.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
      h.setState({
        loading: false
      });
      h.settingState(response);
    });
  }
  render() {
    var { liveEvents, loading } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="livesheet">
        {loading ? 'loading ' : console.log(liveEvents)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [what is JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#jsx).

You need to map your data in `liveEvents` to `ReactElement` / `ReactElement`s array:

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  ...
  render() {
    const { liveEvents, loading } = this.state;
    const { results, fixtures } = liveEvents;

    // Example for rendering all fixture ids
    const fixturesArray = fixtures.map(fixture => (
      <div key={fixture.fixture_id}>{fixture.fixture_id}</div>
    ));

    return (
      <div className="livesheet">{loading ? 'loading' : fixturesArray}</div>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;
```

Also, you don't really need to use `jQuery` with react, read [how to make AJAX calls](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) and all relevant [subject in the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html).

Comment: Before I even use this idea I am sure it will work this is what I was not getting right let me go ahead and apply this

Answer (score 1):

You can put your data in state, and show them in your app (in render)  like this:

```
    <div>{this.state.mydata.map
    (m=><div>m.teamname</div>)}
    </div>
```

**update**
Well if you have want to extract array as well, you should write another map in first map like this:

```
<div>
{this.state.mydata.map(mydata=>
<div>
{mydata.map(myarray=>
 <div>{myarray.teamname}</div>
 )mydata.id
 </div>)}
  </div>
```

Its something like this, you probbly need to check the syntax,if you use two nested map you can extract your array in your data as well
I hope you get the idea and works for you

Comment: I have done that check my code but when I try to access fixtures an error is thrown.

Comment: I cant see  what is the error, the picture you attached seems fine.maybe i am missing something  (I am in traffic ,will check your code  again soon)